Previous and random element buttons in dashboard
I am developing a dashboard in workshop palantir foundry.
I have inserted a filter-list on a certain property of my dataset and displayed a drop-down menu. Now, i would like to insert three buttons, to select the previous, the next and a random element of my list.
Can this be done?
Any help is much appreciated.
I tried to declare a new object set filter and to insert a button widget but i could not figure it out how to proceed to obtain what i would like to do.
